# How to Hook into WordPress Custom Post Type Dashboard menu items

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, custom-post-type, dashboard

I am working on a WordPress plugin that will use a Custom Post Type.

I have created the Post type the standard WP way using the `register_post_type('wpbp-backgrounds', $args);` with the required args.

Creating the posts in this fashion creates the WP Dashboard menu items I need to access the new Custom Post.

The new menu I have is:

- WP Backgrounds

  - Backgrounds
  - Add New Background

What I would like to do is hook into this Dashboard menu and add a third item which I can link to the plugin settings page. The menu would look like this:

- WP Backgrounds

  - Backgrounds
  - Add New Background
  - Settings

Is this something that is possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page), you can add submenus to your CPT's menu using `'edit.php?post_type=wpbp-backgrounds'` for your `$parent_slug` parameter.